# React Native - How to render row by using map data?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

How can i render the row by using the mapping function and make it like the picture below

[image]

Sample data

```
  [
    {
      name: 'Alibaba Chuah',
      temp: '37',
      checkIn: true,
      checkOut: false,
    },

    {
      name: 'Calvin Lee',
      temp: '37',
      checkIn: true,
      checkOut: false,
    }
  ]
```

Comment: take a look i posted sample solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58443723/6544460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In react**

```
let arr = [
      {
        name: 'Alibaba Chuah',
        temp: '37',
        checkIn: true,
        checkOut: false,
      },

      {
        name: 'Calvin Lee',
        temp: '37',
        checkIn: false,
        checkOut: false,
      }
    ]
    function App(){
      return (
        <div>
         {arr.map((item, index)=>
          <div key={index.toString()} 
          style={{display:'flex', 
          justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
          <span>{item.name}</span>
          <span>{item.temp}</span>
          <span style={{background:item.checkIn?'lightblue':''}}> 
          {item.checkIn?'CheckIn':'6:18 Am'}</span>
          </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
     }
```

**In React Native**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <View> 
      {arr.map(item=>
        <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text>{item.temp}</Text>
        <Text 
        style={{background:item.checkIn?'lightblue':''}}>
        {item.checkIn?'CheckIn':'6:18 Am'}</Text>
      </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    display:'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

React-native provides **FlistList** component. You can easily use this to render an array of objects into your mobile view.
For more details - [React native flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist)